# I want to add two files together line by line?

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I am having to files.txt as mentioned below.

```
File1.txt |s File2.txt:
-----------------------                                        
P4-L5, 107MH62, 10.33.145.166, P4:R1:09 |s 10.33.145.166, 1, 3
P4-L21, 108LH62, 10.33.209.168, P4:R3:10 |s 10.33.209.168, 2, 5
P5-L16, 108MH62, 10.34.61.116, P5:R2:16 |s 10.34.61.116, 5, 8
P4-L13, 109LH62, 10.33.177.168, P4:R2:09 |s 10.33.177.168, 10, 12
```

I want to compare the IP address and then add the respective numbers from file2.txt to file1.txt

```
Output file should be like:
---------------------------
|P4-L5, 107MH62, 10.33.145.166, P4:R1:09, 1, 3|
|P4-L21, 108LH62, 10.33.209.168, P4:R3:10, 2, 5|
|P5-L16, 108MH62, 10.34.61.116, P5:R2:16, 5, 8|
|P4-L13, 109LH62, 10.33.177.168, P4:R2:09, 10, 12|
```

Kindly help me with bash or python commands for this!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format the expected input and output please. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i've tried this "paste file1.txt file2.txt > fileresults.txt" command to merge to files. but i want to compare the column of both a file and add the 2nd file content respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> join -t ',' -1 3 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.2 2.3 file1 file2
P4-L5,107MH62,10.33.145.166,P4:R1:09,1,3
P4-L21,108LH62,10.33.209.168,P4:R3:10,2,5
P5-L16,108MH62,10.34.61.116,P5:R2:16,5,8
P4-L13,109LH62,10.33.177.168,P4:R2:09,10,12
```

---

Non-matching example using `-e` option:

```
join -t ',' -1 3 -2 1 -e 'NA' -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.2 2.3 -a1 file1 file2
P4-L5,107MH62,10.33.145.166,1,3
P4-L21,108LH62,10.33.209.168,2,5
P5-L16,108MH62,10.34.61.116,5,8
P4-L13,109LH62,10.33.177.168,NA,NA
```

---

Explanation:

- `-t','`: use CHAR as input and output field separator
- `-1 3`: use 3rd field of file1 as join key
- `-2 1`: use 1st field of file2 as join key
- `-o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.2 2.3`:  obey FORMAT while constructing output line. (first field in first file: 1.1)
- `-e 'NA'`: replace missing input fields with `NA`

Use command `join --help` for more details.